# How to get notification email every time an IP address of a website (dynamic DNS) gets changed?

Tags: batch-file, ip-address

My weekly task is to monitor the IP address from a list of my company's site with different port, the IP address is stored in txt file, for example:

```
http://name1.domain.net:port 
http://name2.domain.net:port2
http://name4.domain.net:port4
```

I used to use chrome extension "IP Address and Domain Information" to get the IP address manually every 3 days and paste the change to another txt file but now my supervisor want to check those IP list every 12 hours.

This process take me a lot of time (around 40 address and getting more). Is there any program or bash code to make automatic this process and just send me the an email if some of those address has been down or getting another IP address? For example, the email content should look like this:

```
http://name4.domain.net:port4 - server "UP" - "New IPv4 address"
http://name1.domain.net:port4 - server "Down" - "IPv4 address"
```

Comment: what OS are you running? Checking upness and current IPs is trivial - simply pinging the domain would do to check IP, and tools like curl might help check if a web page is up on a domainIP. Figuring out if its changed depends very much on the OS. If you really want to do it right, set up some sort of monitoring.

Comment: I'm currently using win 10, Im learning to use Linux mint too, my supervisor said this process can help the company client site more security by analyze it? ( I dunno i just get this job) :(

Answer (score 2):

Well.... it's school holidays for me, and I'm *super bored* today, so I decided to make a Python script that does what you need, and can automatically send you an email detailing the changes. It'll check the IPs of the sites you specify in `urls` every 12 hours. It should work.

This answer probably belongs on StackOverflow, but leave me alone >:(

I've added comments detailing what each thingo does

```python
import requests, smtplib, time

# Put the urls of the servers you wanna check here (makes sure to specify http:// or https://)
urls = ['https://google.com', 'https://pigeonburger.xyz']
print("Checking websites:", str(urls))

def checkSites():
        while True:
            siteIPs = []

            # For each site in the list, get their IP and append it to another list for future checking. current_ips is what we'll be checking against.
            for site in urls:
                request = requests.get(site, stream=True)
                siteIPs.append([site, request.raw._connection.sock.getpeername()[0]])
                current_ips = siteIPs

            print("Current site IPs:", str(current_ips))

            # While the latest check of IPs is equal to the first check (i.e there has been no IP change). This loop will run every 12 hours (43200 seconds)
            while siteIPs == current_ips:
                print("No changes found. Checking the sites IPs again in 12 hours")
                time.sleep(43200)
                print("Checking sites IPs again......")
                siteIPs = []
                for site in urls:
                    request = requests.get(site, stream=True)
                    siteIPs.append([site, request.raw._connection.sock.getpeername()[0]])

            # Once the loop is broken, and a change is detected, find what site's IP was changed.
            print("An IP change(s) was detected! Locating the exact change now.....")
            def find_difference(x, y):
                list_difference = [i for i in x+y if i not in x]
                return list_difference

            site_diffs = find_difference(siteIPs, current_ips)

            # Generates a line to be included in the email detailing what the sites IP has changed to - a new line for each change.
            email_content = []
            for site_data in site_diffs:
                email_content.append(f"The IP of {site_data[0]} has changed to {site_data[1]}")
            print('\n'.join(email_content))

            # Send an email containing the info on the changes.
            print("Sending email containing the changes now......")
            sendMail('\n'.join(email_content))
            print("Email sent! Program will restart now.")


# This is the function that sends the email. Update the email addresses and SMTP server info to meet your needs.
def sendMail(content):
    sender = 'sender@google.com'
    receivers = ['receiver@example.com']

    message = f"""From: Server <sender@google.com>
    To: Your email <receiver@example.com>
    Subject: Site IP Updated
    
    {content}
    """

    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.example.com', port=587)
    smtpObj.connect("smtp.example.com", port=587)
    smtpObj.ehlo()
    smtpObj.starttls()
    smtpObj.login("username", "password")
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)

# Start
if __name__ == '__main__':
    checkSites()
```

To anyone reading this - let me know if there are any potential errors with the script or ways to make it more efficient. This isn't my best code lol

Comment: Can you point out what do i miss, i try to edit some line and run but it no respond back:
`1. urls = ['http://name1.domain.net:81', 'http://name2.domain.net:82']`
`2. def sendMail(content):
    sender = 'myemail1@gmail.com'
    receivers = ['myemail2@example.com']
    message = f"""From: Server <myemail1@gmail.com>
    To: Your email <myemail2@gmail.com>
    Subject: Site IP Updated
    
    {content}
    """

    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.google.com', port=587)
    smtpObj.connect("smtp.google.com", port=587)
    smtpObj.login("myemail1@gmail.com", "email1 password")

Comment: You're using `smtp.google.com`, which is incorrect. Change them all to `smtp.gmail.com`. Everything else should work.

Comment: how can i know the code is working? when i run it just idle. BTW thanks for help and respond so fast Mr. @pigeonburger

Comment: I have edited my answer to add multiple `print` statements to show what it is doing.

Comment: Dear @pigeonburger, your script is working fine but i have one more question: Does this script work when 1 of urls site temporary down at someday? (for ex: 24 hour after first run) when i try to add 1 of dead urls site at first run it give me a lot of error code and don't show the other site ip. I want to ensure that if one or more of urls site getting down, so i can still receive a notification to my email and investigate it?